# Where can I find repeated measures data arising from longitudinal studies involving psychometric tests?

Tags: data-request, longitudinal

Where can I find repeated measures data arising from longitudinal studies involving psychometric tests?

I'm mostly interested in mental health data but I am open to other suggestions.